# Error loading System.Management.Automation assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, assemblybinding

I am developing a WPF application which is running a powershell script.

```
string scriptPath = "/script/myscript.ps1";
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptPath);
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

I have added the following assembly.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\System.Management.Automation.dll
```

But when program runs following exception comes;

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)":"System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}**

When I search this error I can find some answers. But those are not clear for me. 
Please advice me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix my issue. This is what I does;
open my **.csproj** file
search for  System.Management.Automation reference.
Replace that with the following `<Reference Include="System.Management.Automation" />`
These steps fixed my issue