# Azure DevOps release pipeline - How to resolve Strong Name Validation issue

Tags: c#, dll, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a C# exe which is referring to some other dlls and the dlls are signed using a strong name key. It works fine when I execute this in my local system. But when I call the same exe from Azure release pipeline, it is giving me the below error.

System.Security.SecurityException: Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

I tried sn.exe -Vr "dll path" for all the referred dlls. And also tried the command bypassTrustedAppStrongNames enabled="false" & "true" within the exe's app.config. But both didn't help.

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to search for System.Management.Automation reference in the csproj file and replace that with `<Reference Include="System.Management.Automation" />`

For this ,please refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219885/strong-name-validation-failed-for-application) with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable the strong name validation in an application level by adding the following snippet in an [Application Configuration File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/)

```
<configuration>  
  <runtime>  
    <bypassTrustedAppStrongNames enabled="true" />  
  </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

For more info you can take a look in [Microsoft documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/disable-strong-name-bypass-feature)

Comment: Hi Stelios, Already tried this, but it didn't help. As mentioned, locally it works fine, but when it call from the pipeline it gives error.

Comment: @Tinz habe you tried to disable it on a server level? as it is discribed in the Microsoft's documentation page I attached to you? Disable the strong-name bypass feature for all applications - Subtopic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you will have permissions to skip validation on a hosted agent. So you can either make your own agent or

- Remove the strong name of the dependencies or rebuild them with no strong name.
- Sign your application.

Comment: I have added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\x64\sn.exe" -Vr "{dll Path}" in the hosted agent commandline task before calling exe and it is showing 'Verification entry added for assembly', but again it is showing Strong name validation failed.

Comment: Skipping verification is a local workaround. Strong name sign your assemblies.